# DELIMITER Not found during Amazon Copy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have added a `Delimiter ','` but then too I am getting an error.

Code:

```
"copy %s.%s_tmp
from '%s'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=%s;aws_secret_access_key=%s'
REMOVEQUOTES
ESCAPE
ACCEPTINVCHARS
ENCODING AS UTF8
DELIMITER ','
GZIP
ACCEPTANYDATE
region '%s'"
% (schema, table, s3_path, access_key, secret_key, region)
```

Error:

> InternalError: Load into table 'my_table' failed.  Check 'stl_load_errors' system table for details.

In this table in Redshift the error is `Delimiter not found`

How can I fix this?

**One of the raw line is in this format :**

> 1122,"",4332345,"2016-07-28 15:00:09","2032-09-28
>   15:00:09",19.00,"","some string","","som string","abc","abc","abc"

Comment: Can you edit your question and show us the contents of the row that Redshift attempted to load? It should be shown in the `stl_load_errors` table as `raw_line`.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein aadded raw line in this format , though there are many others in same format

Comment: And how many columns are in the target table? That sample line has 13 column. (Was that one of the failed lines?)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes one of the failed lines was this  and columns are exactly 13 , two more are there but those are time stamps with default values

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `MAXERROR` parameter in the copy command. IT will succeed you partial load even though some records are in error.

Also try using this version of `COPY`:

```
copy tblname(col1,col2,col3...) from s3 path
```